PayPal doesn't send Webhooks to my Azure subdomains
I'm attempting to receive webhooks from PayPal, using their webhook simulator, on my website located at mysite-dev.azurewebsites.net.
The issue is that PayPal won't sendwebhooks to my designated endpoint at mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/paypal/webhook. However, it does successfully send webhooks to webhook.site/9fe3c09c-f710-4fe0-b21d-bde41670ea34.
It seems that the problem may stem from the domain azurewebsites.net. In an attempt to resolve this, I switched to dev.mysite.com/api/paypal/webhook, but unfortunately that didn't work either.
It's only when I switched to using a top-level domain (instead of a subdomain), such as mysite.com, that the webhooks start working consistently. I can reliably receive all PayPal webhooks at mysite.com/api/paypal/webhook.
Why won't PayPal send to URLs with a subdomain?

What is the actual domain? Test it at URL filtering services like https://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com/
